# Why doesn't libgdx button work every time?

Tags: java, libgdx

I made a button, witch stops the game. The is a menu, where you can continue the game. But if the cam moves with the player, the button doesn't work any more. You can see it, but if you click on it nothing happens. If you come back to the "start position" of the cam, the button works again. But the InputProcessor is always the stage with the button.

```
public class PlayState extends State {

    //Objects
    private final GameStateManager gameStateManager;
    private final State me;
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private Player player;
    private Texture background;
    private Texture filter;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private Sound click, boost;
    private Drug drug;
    private Border border;
    private House house;


    //Constants
    public static final int FIELD_SIZE_HEIGHT = 1000;
    public static final int FIELD_SIZE_WIDTH = 500;

    //Variables
    private int collectedDrugs;
    private boolean pause, renderLost;
    private boolean boostSound;

    //Button pause
    private Stage stage;
    private ImageButton button;
    private Drawable drawable;
    private Texture textureBtn;

    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        gameStateManager = gsm;
        me = this;
        entityManager = new EntityManager();
        player = new Player(this, 100, 100);
        border = new Border();
        background = new Texture("bggame.png");
        filter = new Texture("filter.png");
        cam.setToOrtho(false, MinniMafia.WIDTH, MinniMafia.HEIGHT);
        click = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Click.mp3"));
        boost = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("boost.mp3"));
        drug = new Drug();
        house = new House();
        collectedDrugs = 0;
        font = new BitmapFont();
        entityManager.addEntity(player);
        entityManager.addEntity(drug);
        entityManager.addEntity(border);
        entityManager.addEntity(house);

        pause = false;
        renderLost = false;
        boostSound = false;

        stage = new Stage();
        textureBtn = new Texture("pausebtn.png");
        drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(textureBtn));
        button = new ImageButton(drawable);
        button.setPosition(cam.position.x + cam.viewportWidth/2 - 50, cam.position.y + cam.viewportHeight/2 - 50);
        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)  {
                gameStateManager.set(new PauseState(gameStateManager, me));
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(button);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(button.getStage());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            click.play(0.2f);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            player.setStop(true);
            boostSound = false;
        } else {
            if (!boostSound) {
                boost.play(0.2f);
                boostSound = true;
            }
            player.setStop(false);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        if(Gdx.input.getInputProcessor() == stage){
            System.out.println("All working");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        if (!pause) {
            handleInput();
            entityManager.updateEntities(dt);
            setCam();
            button.setPosition(cam.position.x + cam.viewportWidth/2 - 60, cam.position.y + cam.viewportHeight/2 - 60);
            if (drug.collides(player.getBounds())) {
                entityManager.disposeEntity(drug);
                player.setGotDrug(true);
            }
            if (border.collides(player.getBounds()) && !border.isOpen()) {
                pause = true;
                renderLost = true;

            }
            if (house.collides(player.getBounds()) && player.isGotDrug()) {
                player.setGotDrug(false);
                collectedDrugs++;
                drug = new Drug();
                entityManager.addEntity(drug);
            }
        } else if (renderLost = true) {
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));
                dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(background, 0, 0);
        entityManager.renderEntities(sb);
        button.draw(sb, 10f);
        font.draw(sb, "" + collectedDrugs, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2 + 10, cam.position.y - cam.viewportHeight / 2 + 20);
        if (renderLost) {
            sb.draw(filter, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.position.y - cam.viewportHeight / 2);
            font.draw(sb, "LOST! SCORE:" + collectedDrugs, cam.position.x - 50, cam.position.y);
        }
        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        background.dispose();
        entityManager.disposeAll();
        click.dispose();
    }

    private void setCam() {

        float camViewportHalfX = cam.viewportWidth * .5f;
        float camViewportHalfY = cam.viewportHeight * .5f;

        cam.position.x = player.getPosition().x;
        cam.position.y = player.getPosition().y;
        cam.position.x = MathUtils.clamp(cam.position.x, camViewportHalfX, FIELD_SIZE_WIDTH - camViewportHalfX);
        cam.position.y = MathUtils.clamp(cam.position.y, camViewportHalfY, FIELD_SIZE_HEIGHT - camViewportHalfY);

        cam.update();
    }

    public Drug getDrug() {
        return drug;
    }

    public House getHouse() {
        return house;
    }
}
```

I really don't know where the problem is. Could you help me please?

Comment: The problem is that you're drawing your button (and 9ther UI elements) with the same camera as your game. You should be letting the Stage draw the button by calling stage.draw() after sb.end().

Comment: You should also be calling stage.act() so it can manage the button press.

Comment: where should i calling stage.act?

Comment: I don't know how your code is organized but it would typically be at the beginning of render(), before you draw anything. Since you have an update() method that I assume you call before your render() method, I would put it in update().